# How to cancel first iteration of a function if function is reactivated

Tags: javascript, function, fade

I have a function that takes about 10 seconds to complete and it breaks if reactivated before the first iteration is completed - It acts as a text-fader - **JQuery is not an option I want to use pure JS**

My function:

```
//Text fading effect
function fadeText() {
    var hex1 = 153,
    hex2 = 204,
    hex3 = 51;
    function innerFade() {
        if (hex1 >= 30) {
            hex1 -= 1;
            document.getElementById('confirmation').style.color = "rgb(" + hex1 + "," + hex2 + "," + hex3 + ")";
        }
        if (hex2 >= 30) {
            hex2 -= 1;
            document.getElementById('confirmation').style.color = "rgb(" + hex1 + "," + hex2 + "," + hex3 + ")";
        }
        if (hex3 >= 30) {
            hex3 -= 1;
            document.getElementById('confirmation').style.color = "rgb(" + hex1 + "," + hex2 + "," + hex3 + ")";
        }
        setTimeout(innerFade, 20);
    }
    innerFade();
}
```

This is activated on button press, I want the first iteration to cancel or set the `innerHTML` of the div the text has been assigned to to `innerHTML="";` if it is activated again before the animation is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Big Edit:**

```
//Set colour function
function setColor(elementName, r, g, b) {
    document.getElementById(elementName).style.color = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

//Text fading effect

var animationActive = false;

function fadeText() {

    if (animationActive) return;

    animationActive = true;

    var hex1 = 153,
    hex2 = 204,
    hex3 = 51;

    function innerFade() {

        var rDone, gDone, bDone;

        if (hex1 >= 30) {
            hex1 -= 1;
            setColor('confirmation', hex1, hex2, hex3);
        } else {rDone = true;}

        if (hex2 >= 30) {
            hex2 -= 1;
            setColor('confirmation', hex1, hex2, hex3);
        } else {gDone = true;}

        if (hex3 >= 30) {
            hex3 -= 1;
            setColor('confirmation', hex1, hex2, hex3);
        } else {bDone = true;}

        if (rDone && gDone && bDone) {
            animationActive = false;
        }

    }
    setTimeout(innerFade, 20);

}
```

Comment: @NiklasRingdahl - Sorry that doesn't work man, here is my implementation of it: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/q4CqZ/16/

Comment: Sorry to hear, but in that fiddle the code doesn't look like I intended. Will try to edit and make it work.

Comment: Gaah, I don't understand Fiddler! :-( But I reworked the function blindly, this is more like the way I imagined it. Just for my curiosity - why is jQuery out of the question?

Comment: @NiklasRingdahl - Thanks very much! You pushed me in the right direction, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/q4CqZ/29/

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button to prevent calling the function again:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="fadeText(this)"> Fade text </button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function fadeText(btn) {
    var elm = document.getElementById('confirmation'),
        c = [153, 204, 51];

    function loop() {
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            if (c[i] >= 30) c[i] -= 1;
        }
        elm.style.color = 'rgb(' + c[0] + ',' + c[1] + ',' + c[2] + ')';
        return c[0] < 30 && c[1] < 30 && c[2] < 30 ? 
                btn.disabled = false : setTimeout(loop, 20);
    }

    btn.disabled = true;
    loop();
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nKV7A/